# Substitute two empty lines in a file with one empty line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line, grep

This is the input of example1:

```
a


b
```

And the output:

```
a

b
```

This is the input of example2:

```
a




b
```

And the output:

```
a


b
```

But, with a huge file. What I have tried: `sed 's/\n\n/\n/g' file` amd `cat file | tr '\n' '\t' | sed 's/\t\t/\t/g' | tr '\t' '\n'`

Comment: What if there are 3 or more adjacent blank lines?  Do you need each pair of blank lines to be replaced with a single blank line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also possible with sed

```
sed '/^$/N;/^\n$/ s/\n//' <your_filename>
```

will read the next (after an empty) line into the pattern space and, if it's also empty, remove \n

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want two `\n\n` replaced with one `\n`, just set the `RS` in `gawk` to do that:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"} 1' file
```

If you want runs of `\n` replaced, any number, with a single `\n` set `awk` to paragraph mode:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="" } 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

sed reads 1 `\n`-terminated line at a time so you can't do `s/\n\n/anything` since there will never be any `\n`s in the buffer.

Just use awk:

```
awk -v RS= '1' file
```

The above will replace all sequences of empty lines by a single blank line. If that's not what you need then update your example.